# Button with ssjs and csjs not openning new window in csjs

Tags: xpages

I have a button when clicked, updates the backend document then opens a new windows to another website passing in some information.

It works just fine in Mozilla v27 however, testing it in IE 10 or 11 and Chrome, it doesn't work.  UGH.  Can anyone suggest a better way to handle this so it works in all browsers. . .
Updated:  All Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
<xp:this.resources>
<xp:script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" clientSide="true" />
<xp:script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.min.js" clientSide="true" />
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[
function linkToEstatementsSignup() 
{
var url = " https://ebppdemo.documentdna.com/lieberman/login.aspx?uid=#{javascript:userOccupantProfile.gettenant_id()}" +
"&fn=#{javascript:userOccupantProfile.getFirstName()}" +  
"&ln=#{javascript:userOccupantProfile.getLastName()}" +
"&em=#{javascript:userOccupantProfile.getEmail()}" +  
"&ph=#{javascript:userOccupantProfile.getDayPhone()}" +
"&acct=#{javascript:userOccupantProfile.getAccountNumber()}";

alert( url );

window.open( url );
}
]]>
</xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>

<xe:navigator id="navigator1">
<xe:this.treeNodes>
<xe:basicContainerNode label="Register for e-Statements"
submitValue="RegisterForEstatements" enabled="true">
<xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:myEStatements.renderStatements()}]]>
</xe:this.rendered>
</xe:basicContainerNode>
</xe:this.treeNodes>
<xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
refreshMode="partial" refreshId="navigator1">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if( context.getSubmittedValue() == "RegisterForEstatements" )
{
sessionScope.put( "dialogAcceptEStatementTitle", "Accept e-Statements!" );
var dialogAcceptEstatements = getComponent( "dlgAcceptEStatements" );
dialogAcceptEstatements.show();
return "";
}       

sessionScope.put( "dialogOopsTitle", "Oopps!" );
sessionScope.put( "dialogOopsMessage", "\nThis Feature Has Not Been Enabled Yet!" );
var dialogOops = getComponent( "dialogOops" );
dialogOops.show();
return "";

}]]>
</xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xe:navigator>
</xp:view>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
<xp:this.resources>
<xp:script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" clientSide="true" />
<xp:script src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.min.js" clientSide="true" />
<xp:script src="js/jquery.panelgallery-2.0.0.min.js"
clientSide="true" />
<xp:styleSheet href="/eStarTheme.css" />
<xp:script src="/jsDominoGlobals.jss" clientSide="false"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:this.data>
<xp:dominoDocument var="selectedOccupant"
databaseName="star/lms.nsf" formName="fOccupant" action="editDocument">
<xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:return sessionScope.get("OccupantUNID");}]]></xp:this.documentId>
</xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>

<xe:dialog id="dlgAcceptEStatements"
title="#{javascript:sessionScope.dialogAcceptEStatementTitle;}">
<xp:panel>
<xp:table>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Electronic Acceptance" id="acceptEStatementsTitle_Label1"
for="acceptEStatementsTitle1">
</xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:div styleClass="lotusMessage lotusInfo" role="alert">
<xp:inputTextarea id="acceptedMessage" readonly="true"
style="width:auto">
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:myEStatements.getEStatementAcceptMessage()}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:inputTextarea>
</xp:div>
</xp:td>
</xp:tr>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
<xp:label value="Check if you accept the verbiage above"
id="acceptEStatementsURL_Label1" for="acceptEStatementsAccept1">
</xp:label>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:checkBox text="" id="acceptEStatementsChecked"
value="#{selectedOccupant.EStatementsAccepted}"></xp:checkBox>
</xp:td>

</xp:tr>
<xp:tr>
<xp:td>
</xp:td>
<xp:td>
<xp:button value="Save" id="btnSave">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
selectedOccupant.replaceItemValue( "EStatementsAccepted", getComponent( "acceptEStatementsChecked" ).getValue() );
selectedOccupant.replaceItemValue( "EStatementsAcceptMessage", getComponent( "acceptedMessage" ).getValue() );
selectedOccupant.replaceItemValue( "EStatementsAcceptedDate", new Date() );
selectedOccupant.save();
getComponent( "dlgAcceptEStatements" ).hide();
}]]></xp:this.action>
<xp:this.onComplete>
<![CDATA[linkToEstatementsSignup();]]>
</xp:this.onComplete>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:button value="Cancel" id="btnCancel">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent( "dlgAcceptEStatements" ).hide();}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
</xp:td>
</xp:tr>
</xp:table>
</xp:panel>
</xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Launching new windows is very sensitive to browser implementation, user preferences, corporate policies, ad blockers, and so on. Even if it isn't blocked, the browser may force it to be a new tab instead of a new window. A better way to handle it would be to wrap the additional content in an instance of the dialog component from the Extension Library so that visually it looks like a new window but isn't.

Comment: Tim, I need to take the user to a 3rd party site.  Not sure I can do that.  I'm OK with opening a new window or tab as we require enabling popups but I am struggling for sure with it working on different versions of browsers.

Comment: Then use an iframe inside a dialog. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the clientside code in the onComplete event:

```
<xp:button id="button29" value="button29">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dlgAcceptEStatements">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            selectedOccupant.replaceItemValue( "EStatementsAccepted", getComponent("acceptEStatementsChecked" ).getValue() );
            selectedOccupant.replaceItemValue( "EStatementsAcceptMessage", getComponent( "acceptedMessage" ).getValue() );
            selectedOccupant.replaceItemValue( "EStatementsAcceptedDate", new Date() );
            selectedOccupant.save();
            getComponent( "dlgAcceptEStatements" ).hide();
        }]]></xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.onComplete>
            <![CDATA[linkToEstatementsSignup();]]>
        </xp:this.onComplete>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button
```

---

Bonus: if acceptEStatementsChecked and acceptedMessage are fields in your datasource, then consider using the datasource getValue() method instead of the component getValue() method (e.g. `document1.getValue("acceptEStatementsChecked")` instead of `getComponent("acceptEStatementsChecked" ).getValue()`).

Comment: The on complete got me a bit further.  I am now getting another error message that says "An error occurred while updating some of the page. 'linkToEstatementSignup' is undefined".  I will update my post with the entire code of both custom controls

Comment: Remember to include your function linkToEstatementsSignup() in your page. It doesn't seem to be part of the XPage (assuming your question contains the latest code)

Comment: The dialog box that calls the linkToEstatementsSignup() function is in the custom control where the function lives.  This works fine in the latest version of Mozilla without error.  Not in IE or Chrome though.  I did move that function into the dialog box to see if that helped and it gave the same error.